# perl: print output of subroutine to file

Tags: perl, file-handling

How to write the output of a subroutine to file?

```
my $logfile="C:/Test/report_p3.txt";
open(my $tt, ">",$logfile) or die "Can not open file";

foreach (@files)
{
if (($_ ne ".") && ($_ ne ".."))
{
    &getinfo($logdir."/".$_);
    print $tt &getinfo; #Here, I wanna pass the output to the handler
}
}

close $tt;
```

on standard output, &getinfo prints correctly the output.

Comment: As an aside, calling subroutines using a leading `&` hasn't been necessary since Perl 4.

Answer (score 4):

Open a filehandle that outputs into a variable, and select it.
After that all output going into STDOUT will be caught in the variable.
Here is an example:

```
sub output {
    print "test\n";
}

my $out;
open VAROUT, '>', \$out;
select VAROUT;
output();
select STDOUT;
printf "output: %s\n", $out;
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it really necesssary, that the subroutine, whose output you want to pass actually prints something?

Usually you should simply make your sub *return* a string and have the caller decide where to output it.

```
my $logfile="C:/Test/report_p3.txt";
open(my $tt, ">",$logfile) or die "Can not open file";

sub get_log {
  return "some text to log";
}

sub log_write {
  my $log_fh = shift;

  print $log_fh get_log() . "\n";
}

log_write($tt);       # prints to file handle from $tt
log_write(STDOUT);    # prints to STDOUT
```